# Type of lambda function that receives an argument

Tags: c++

I'm trying to receive lambda functions as parameters, however I'm having problem with its types.

Here's how I'm calling the function

```
profile(0, 1000, fps, [](ProfilerVariable<int> &fps){fps.counter++;}, [](ProfilerVariable<int> &fps){fps.counter=0;});
```

Here's how I defined it:

```
template <typename T>
void profile(int index, int intervalInMilliseconds, ProfilerVariable<T>& profilerVariable,
                 std::function<void(ProfilerVariable<T>&)> const &increaseFunction, 
                 std::function<void(ProfilerVariable<T>&)> const &resetFunction)
    {
            increaseFunction(profilerVariable);
            //...
```

I don't see nothing wrong. Return type is void, and it accepts `ProfilerVariable&`:

```
    /home/dev/orwell/cpp/common/ZLRTSPClient.cpp:38:26: error: no matching function for call to 'ZLRTSPClient::profile(int, int, ProfilerVariable<int>&, ZLRTSPClient::init()::<lambda(const toolkit::SockException&)>::<lambda(const Ptr&)>::<lambda(ProfilerVariable<int>&)>, ZLRTSPClient::init()::<lambda(const toolkit::SockException&)>::<lambda(const Ptr&)>::<lambda(ProfilerVariable<int>&)>)'
                         });
                          ^
In file included from /home/dev/orwell/cpp/common/RTSPClient.h:11:0,
                 from /home/dev/orwell/cpp/common/ZLRTSPClient.h:3,
                 from /home/dev/orwell/cpp/common/ZLRTSPClient.cpp:1:
/home/dev/orwell/cpp/common/Profiler.h:41:10: note: candidate: template<class T> void Profiler::profile(int, int, ProfilerVariable<T>&, const std::function<void(ProfilerVariable<T>&)>&, const std::function<void(ProfilerVariable<T>&)>&)
     void profile(int index, int intervalInMilliseconds, ProfilerVariable<T>& profilerVariable,
          ^~~~~~~
/home/dev/orwell/cpp/common/Profiler.h:41:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/dev/orwell/cpp/common/ZLRTSPClient.cpp:38:26: note:   'ZLRTSPClient::init()::<lambda(const toolkit::SockException&)>::<lambda(const Ptr&)>::<lambda(ProfilerVariable<int>&)>' is not derived from 'const std::function<void(ProfilerVariable<T>&)>'
                         });
                          ^
```

PS: what does the `const` in `std::function<void(ProfilerVariable<T>&)> const &increaseFunction` stands for?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `profilerVariable` argument in the call to `profile`? The full and complete error output probably contains a note about wrong number of arguments, please always copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output in questions regarding build errors.

Comment: As for the `const` it's the same as a reference to a constant anything, like e.g. `int const&`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, I updated to solve both problems you mentioned, please take a look

Comment: You need to specify `T` explicitly `profile<int>(0,1000,...)` because `T` cannot be deduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lambda is not `std::function`, so `T` cannot be deduced.

You might get rid of `std::function` and take functor:

```
template <typename T, typename F1, typename >
void profile(int index,
             int intervalInMilliseconds,
             ProfilerVariable<T>& profilerVariable,
             F1 const &increaseFunction,
             F2 const &resetFunction) {/*..*/}
```

or you can make those parameters non deducible:

```
template <typename T>
void profile(int index,
             int intervalInMilliseconds,
             ProfilerVariable<T>& profilerVariable, // Deduce T only here
             std::type_identity_t<std::function<void(ProfilerVariable<T>&)>> const &increaseFunction, 
             std::type_identity_t<std::function<void(ProfilerVariable<T>&)>> const &resetFunction)
```

[`std::type_identity_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) is C++20 but can be implemented for previous version.

Else you have to change in the call site

- be explicit:

  ```
  profile<int>(0, 1000, fps, [](ProfilerVariable<int> &fps){fps.counter++;}, [](ProfilerVariable<int> &fps){fps.counter=0;});
  ```
- or use "correct" arguments

  ```
  profile(0,
          1000,
          fps,
          std::function{[](ProfilerVariable<int> &fps){fps.counter++;}},
          std::function{[](ProfilerVariable<int> &fps){fps.counter=0;}});
  ```